# Google Fonts in HTML

Tags: html, fonts

I am trying to use Londrina Shadow from Google fonts in my HTML code.  I have typed this in the  in HTML:  `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Londrina+Shadow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

The ampersand is blocked out and the link does not appear to be working.

I have typed this in CSS:  font-family: 'Londrina Shadow', cursive;

It does appear to be working.

What is my problem?

Comment: I am having difficulty getting the link to print.  Here it is again.

Comment: You preferably set `font-family` to `body` in CSS. like this: `body { font-family: 'Londrina Shadow', cursive; }`

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61965780/google-fonts-in-html/61965921#61965921

Answer (score 1):

use it like that

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Londrina+Shadow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head> 

<body>

<h1 style="font-family: 'Londrina Shadow'">Checking</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

you are using it in a wrong way